# Extract Polygon Lat/Longs from Geometry Point

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

Let me preface this by stating, I have looked at nearly all the Stackoverflow questions that I have came across, and I can't seem to find anything that works. I'm starting to feel like I'm going about this the wrong way.

I'm have shapes stored in a `Geometry` type. The shape should look like this in my WPF app -

[image]

The problem is that a lot of my Geometry points are of `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`. In my app, I need the polygon lat/long points. The geometry collection contains linestrings too, which I don't need. I only need the polygon points.

Example -

[image]

Is there a way for me to extract the polygon lat/long points via SQL Server? We previously have used the `Geom.STConvexHull()` function, however I need more defined points than what that provides.

Comment: You cannot get the latitude and longitude from an image.  Often the files have the information that may contain the lat/long; or the source of the image (xml or html).

Comment: the points inside linestring are lat/long ?

Comment: @Frenchy Correct. The linestring points are irrelevant to me. I'm just interested in the Polygon shapes

Comment: @Frenchy I suppose if I could just extract all lat/long points, then including the linestring points wouldn't be the end of the world. I'm really just after the boundary points.

Comment: i suppose you are working directly on instance sql? yes i think its very difficult to work directly on sql instance...i see solution with replace..but not easy

Comment: @Frenchy So there isn't a built in way for me to extract all Lat/Long points from a Geometry point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a little helper function like this:

```
create or alter function GetGeometries(@geo geometry, @geometry_type varchar(200) = null)
returns @geometries table (i int primary key, geo geometry)
as
begin
  declare @i int = 1;
  while (1=1)
  begin
    declare @g geometry = @geo.STGeometryN(@i);
    if @g is null break;

    if (@geometry_type is null or @g.InstanceOf(@geometry_type)=1 )
    begin
      insert into @geometries(i,geo)values (@i, @g);
    end
    set @i += 1;
  end

  return;
end

go

create or alter function GetPoints(@geo geometry)
returns @geometries table (i int primary key, point geometry)
as
begin
  declare @i int = 1;
  while (1=1)
  begin
    declare @g geometry = @geo.STPointN(@i);
    if @g is null break;

    insert into @geometries(i,point)values (@i, @g);

    set @i += 1;
  end

  return;
end

go


DECLARE @g geometry = 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(LINESTRING(1 1, 3 5),POLYGON((-1 -1, -1 -5, -5 -5, -5 -1, -1 -1)))';

SELECT g.i geometry_index, p.i point_index, p.point.STX X, p.point.STY Y
from dbo.GetGeometries(@g,'POLYGON') g
outer apply dbo.GetPoints(g.geo) p
```

Comment: This is great. How would I go about passing in an additional parameter to this function to only return points of certain types? i.e. Only polygon shape points instead of linestring, etc.

Comment: I think I just answered my own question. Just added an if statement for checking the type by using ```@geo.STGeometryN(@i).StGeometryType() <> 'Polygon'```

Comment: You can traverse the individual geometries with STGeometryN, before extracting the points with STPointN